# Transform an XML document with XSLT before processing

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have an XML document which I will be processing within a Java application.
However, I need to transform it with an XSLT file to be able to do the processing afterwards.

This is how I am loading the XML file at present.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory;
    DocumentBuilder docbuilder;
    Document doc;
    Element root;

    factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try
    {
        // open up the xml document
        docbuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docbuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(m_strFileName));

        // get the document type
        doctype = doc.getDoctype();
        strDTD = doctype.getPublicId();

        // get the root of the document
        root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        // get the list of child nodes
        nodes = root.getChildNodes();
        // now process each node
        ...
    }
    catch(ParserConfigurationException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SAXException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I apply an XSLT transform to the XML document and then obtain the root node of the new document ?

Note that I am **not** wanting to write the resulting xml tree to disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having done some long research ... finally found the acceptable solution (at least for me).

Here is the sample I was able to adapt with success :

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Templates template = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("xsl.xlt")));
Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer();
Source source = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("in.xml"));
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.newDocument();
Result result = new DOMResult(doc);
xformer.transform(source, result);
```

Taken from here :
[Transforming an XML File with XSL into a DOM Document](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0440__XML/TransforminganXMLFilewithXSLintoaDOMDocument.htm)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Do I understand correctly, that the resulting Document is now stored in `doc`? (what a strange API....)

Comment: @dokaspar - yes you are quite right, the resulting document is indeed held within the variable "doc".

Answer (score 2):

You can transform a `DOMSource` to a `DOMResult`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMResult.html. Note that XSLT/XPath operates on XML with namespaces to make sure you use a document builder factory that is namespace aware.

Comment: +1: `DocumentBuilderFactory` being _non-namespace-aware_ by default is something that used to catch me out every time...

Comment: Hi @Martin, thank you for taking the trouble to answer this.  I was testing the solution I posted above when you put in your answer :-D - +1ed